Convolved gaussian issue
I have this code that aims to fit the data in here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oXTf4Ns60N6-JTI19vr_UKpvEM1qk31m/view?usp=sharing
Where the function read_file is used to extract the information in a proper way.
The issue lies in ensuring proper relations between the amplitudes extracted using the read_file function. Specifically, I aim to establish fixed relationships between these amplitudes. For instance, I intend for the amplitude of the second Gaussian to be half that of the first Gaussian. Similarly, I desire a specific ratio between the amplitudes of the third and fourth Gaussians, such as 3:4.
The desired relationships are as follows:
peak_amplitudes = [1, 0.5996, 0.884*1, 0.884*0.51837]  # amplitude known value

It is possible to do that in my code?
Note as you can see in my code the mean value is being given to the gaussian fit, because is information that i have. And as you can see i also have a problem with the standar devitions that some of them are negative.
And this is the plot that i have so far

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Function to read numeric data from a file
def read_numeric_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='latin1') as f:
        data = []
        live_time = None
        real_time = None
        for line in f:
            if 'LIVE_TIME' in line:
                live_time = line.strip()
            elif 'REAL_TIME' in line:
                real_time = line.strip()
            elif all(char.isdigit() or char in ".-+e" for char in line.strip()):
                row = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
                data.extend(row)
    return np.array(data), live_time, real_time

file_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/ProjetoXRF_Manuel/April2024/20240402_In.mca'
data, _, _ = read_numeric_data(file_path)

a = -0.0188026396003431
b = 0.039549044037714
Data = data
dim = 0

# Function to convolve multiple Gaussians
def multi_gaussian(x, *params):
    eps = 1e-10
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(0, len(params), 3):
        amplitude, mean, sigma = params[i:i+3]
        # Initial parameters for Gaussian peaks
        peak_means = [24.21, 24.002, 27.276, 27.238]  # mean known value
        mean=peak_means[i//3] # to fix the mean value whith the known values
        y += amplitude * np.exp(-(x - mean)**2 / (2 * sigma**2 + eps))
    return y

sigma = []
area = []

# Function to plot the convolved energy spectrum
def plot_convolved_spectrum(Data, a, b, i, ax=None):
    maxim = np.max(Data)
    workingarray = np.squeeze(Data)

    # Define peak points
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(workingarray / maxim, height=0.1)
    peak_values = workingarray[peaks] / maxim
    peak_indices = peaks

    # Calculate energy values corresponding to the peaks
    energy_spectrum = a + b * peak_indices

    # Prepare data for convolution
    data = workingarray[:885] / maxim
    data_y = data / data.max()
    data_x = a + b * np.linspace(0, 885, num=len(data_y))

    # Adjust initial guesses for peak amplitudes based on desired relationships
    peak_amplitudes = [1, 0.5996, 0.884*1, 0.884*0.51837]
    peak_amplitudes[1] = 0.5996 * peak_amplitudes[0]
    peak_amplitudes[2] = 0.884 * peak_amplitudes[0]
    peak_amplitudes[3] = 0.884 * 0.51837 * peak_amplitudes[0]

    peak_sigmas = [0.1] * 4  # to fix the initial values for sigma


    peak_means = [24.21, 24.002, 27.276, 27.238]  # mean known value

    params_init = list(zip(peak_amplitudes, peak_means, peak_sigmas))
    params_init = np.concatenate(params_init)

    # Fit multiple Gaussians to the energy spectrum
    params, params_cov = curve_fit(multi_gaussian, data_x, data_y, p0=params_init)

    # Get a fine interpolation of the fit
    x_fine = np.linspace(data_x.min(), data_x.max(), num=20000)

    # Plot each individual Gaussian with a different color
    for j in range(0, len(params), 3):
        amplitude, mean, sigma = params[j:j+3]
        ax.plot(x_fine, amplitude * np.exp(-(x_fine - mean)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)),
                label=f"Gaussian {j//3 + 1}", linewidth=1.5)

    # Other plotting configurations
    ax.set_xlabel('Energy (KeV)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Normalized Data')
    ax.legend()
    ax.set_title('Convolved Energy Spectrum')

    # Print information
    sigmas_array = params[2::3]
    amplitudes_array = params[::3]
    means_array = params[1::3]
    areas = [peak_amplitudes[i] * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * sigmas_array[i] for i in range(len(sigmas_array))]
    area.append(areas)
    total_area = np.sum(areas)
    print("amplitudes",amplitudes_array)
    print("Standard deviations:", sigmas_array)
    print("Areas:", areas)

# Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_convolved_spectrum(Data, a, b, dim, ax=ax)
ax.set_xlim([a + b * (peak_indices[0] - 30), a + b * (peak_indices[-1] + 50)])
plt.show()

